# Does the following route change include undesired machine?

Tags: windows, networking, route

I want to utilize both the wired lan from the company and the wireless from my phone( achieved by PdaNet ). I need to seperate the connections in the route table because the wireless connection have higher priority ( lower metric ) as seen from the route table.

I know some internal machine and they must be connected using the lan of the company and the corresponding gateway. For example: 10.167.54.4, 10.167.54.5, 10.167.55.10.

The ip address are similar but I don't know their subnet mask. I am gussing 255.255.0.0. So I made the following route change:

route -p add 10.167.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.178.34.250 metric 1 if 14

Would this config include other machine from the internet thus making some browsing fail? Maybe 10.167.56.0 is owned by other company? Should I add route rule for the smallest subnet? i.g: 10.167.54.0, 10.167.55.0

Comment: Have we answered your question?  Is there any more information we can assist with?

Answer (score 1):

> Would this config include other machine from the internet thus making some browsing fail?

It's unlikely in this particular case, since you're asking about an [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) address

> Maybe 10.167.56.0 is owned by other company?

It's possible that your company has B2B connection to another partner that uses this subnet, or that this subnet is reserved for something else.  How could we know that though?  You need to talk to your IT networking department for this question.

> Should I add route rule for the smallest subnet? i.g: 10.167.54.0, 10.167.55.0

See previous answer.

```
route -p add 10.167.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.178.34.250 metric 1 if 14
```

Please be sure that `10.178.34.250` is directly connected to interface 14's subnet.